# Calculating percentage while using case expression to categorize prices

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have got a table called `Property_Median_Price`. I need to categorize the properties into four groups based on their price range. Below is the code I came up and it worked fine.

```
SELECT Price_Range, 
    count(*) AS Property_Number
FROM (
    SELECT (CASE
        WHEN PMP.Median_Price > 2500000 THEN '$2.5M+'
        WHEN PMP.Median_Price > 1500000 THEN '$1.5M-$2.5M'
        WHEN PMP.Median_Price > 750000 THEN '$750K-$1.5M'
        WHEN PMP.Median_Price <= 750000 THEN '0-$750K'
        END) AS Price_Range
    FROM Property_Median_Price AS PMP
) PMP
GROUP BY Price_Range
ORDER BY Property_Number DESC;
```

I would also like to find out the percentage of each category and came up with the code below

```
SELECT 
    Price_Range, 
    count(*) AS Property_Number,
    concat(round(count(*)/sum(count(*)),4)*100,'%') 
FROM (
    SELECT (CASE
        WHEN PMP.Median_Price > 2500000 THEN '$2.5M+'
        WHEN PMP.Median_Price > 1500000 THEN '$1.5M-$2.5M'
        WHEN PMP.Median_Price > 750000 THEN '$750K-$1.5M'
        WHEN PMP.Median_Price <= 750000 THEN '0-$750K'
        END) AS Price_Range
    FROM Property_Median_Price AS PMP
) PMP
GROUP BY Price_Range
ORDER BY Property_Number DESC;
```

But I'm getting the following error:

> Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.

How can solve this?

Comment: You don't need brackets around a case expression.

Comment: Saying [it didn't work](https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/) is not useful. How? Have a look at [Ntile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/ntile-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: You can do: count(*) / (1.0 * sum(count(*)) over()) which should work. 1.0 is to get float values

Comment: `1.0` gets a *numeric* value, not *float* (which is totally the wrong data type for anything to do with monetary values).

Comment: @DaleK thank you dale! for your insight and editing work you are awesome!

Comment: @Stu "Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery." this is the error prompt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sum(count(*))` is not a valid operation, causing :

> Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an
> aggregate or a subquery

You will need to do it as follows :

```
select *,  concat(round(cast(Property_Number as float)/sum(Property_Number) over(), 4)*100, '%') as percentage
from (
  SELECT Price_Range, 
    count(*) AS Property_Number
  FROM (
    SELECT (CASE
        WHEN PMP.Median_Price > 2500000 THEN '$2.5M+'
        WHEN PMP.Median_Price > 1500000 THEN '$1.5M-$2.5M'
        WHEN PMP.Median_Price > 750000 THEN '$750K-$1.5M'
        WHEN PMP.Median_Price <= 750000 THEN '0-$750K'
        END) AS Price_Range
    FROM Property_Median_Price AS PMP
  ) PMP
  GROUP BY Price_Range
) as s
ORDER BY Property_Number DESC
```

Comment: it worked!!!! thank you so much for your concise, insightful and remarkably helpful solution. how can i follow you!!!! lol. i am not senior enough to vote yet but here's a manual "THIS ANSWER IS BLOODY USEFUL!".

Comment: done! can i ask a question, why do we need the 'as s' before the last order by clause? seems to be purely for the sake of syntax?

Comment: The alias (temporary name) is requered so that it can be uniquely identified in the query.

Answer (score 0):

A more compact approach without subqueries:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN PMP.Median_Price >  2500000 THEN      '$2.5M+'
            WHEN PMP.Median_Price >  1500000 THEN '$1.5M-$2.5M'
            WHEN PMP.Median_Price >   750000 THEN '$750K-$1.5M'
            WHEN PMP.Median_Price <=  750000 THEN     '0-$750K' END AS Price_Range, 
       COUNT(*)                                                     AS Property_Number,
       CONCAT(ROUND(100.0 * COUNT(*)/SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER(),4),'%')   AS Percentage
FROM Property_Median_Price AS PMP
GROUP BY CASE WHEN PMP.Median_Price >  2500000 THEN      '$2.5M+'
              WHEN PMP.Median_Price >  1500000 THEN '$1.5M-$2.5M'
              WHEN PMP.Median_Price >   750000 THEN '$750K-$1.5M'
              WHEN PMP.Median_Price <=  750000 THEN     '0-$750K' END
ORDER BY Property_Number DESC;
```

Comment: hi  lemon. it didnt work, error prompt "Invalid column name 'Price_Range'."

Comment: Yeah the aliasing isn't getting assigned if not after the execution of the group by clause. Try this updated version.

Comment: still didnt work. error "Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference."

Comment: it did! the percentage came out as 69.918700000000% but it did! i assume that's got something to do data type. thank you lemon for the alternative approach.